# FROM is not valid at this position. UPDATE statement

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update

I have this code from an online SQL Server tutorial. I need to convert it for MySql. I have already changed `ISNULL` to `ifnull`, but I still have the error from the question title:

```
UPDATE a 
SET PropertyAddress = ifnull(a.PropertyAddress, b.PropertyAddress)
FROM Nashvillehousing as a 
JOIN Nashvillehousing as b
    ON a.ParcelID = b.ParcelID
    AND a.UniqueID <> b.UniqueID
WHERE a.PropertyAddress IS NULL;
```

How can I fix this to run on MySql?

Comment: **MySQL is not MS SQL Server**. Please clarify and use the correct tags in your question.

Comment: I have removed all product specific tags, please specify the tag of the product you're actually using.

Comment: Note that if `ifnull` should be `isnull` then it's redundant since `a.propertyaddress` is *always* NULL with `WHERE a.PropertyAddress IS NULL`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a join for this.

```
UPDATE nashvillehousing 
SET propertyaddress = 
(
  SELECT ANY_VALUE(src.propertyaddress)
  FROM (select * from nashvillehousing) src
  WHERE src.parcelid = nashvillehousing.parcelid
  AND src.uniqueid <> nashvillehousing.uniqueid
)
WHERE propertyaddress IS NULL;
```

I had to write `FROM (select * from nashvillehousing) src` instead of a mere `FROM nashvillehousing src`. That is due to a limitation in MySQL where you cannot directly select from the same table that you are updating.

The original statement assumes that you find at most two rows for a parcelid. This is usually not guaranteed to be the case, so I put in `ANY_VALUE` to get this safe. (You can of course just as well use `MIN` or `MAX` here, if you like this better.)

Answer (score -1):

The MySql syntax for using a JOIN in an UPDATE is different from SQL Server. I don't write this for MySql very often, but I think you want this:

```
UPDATE Nashvillehouse as a 
INNER JOIN Nashvillehouse as b 
    ON a.ParcelID = b.ParcelID
    AND a.UniqueID <> b.UniqueID
SET a.PropertyAddress = ifnull(a.PropertyAddress, b.PropertyAddress)
WHERE a.PropertyAddress IS NULL;
```

Comment: I'm not sure why you reopened the question, when you're basically giving the same answer as the original duplicate.

Comment: I downvoted because you opened a duplicate question and posted the same answer as the duplicate link.